# how to import a text file into phpmyadmin or mysql database

Tags: mysql, linux, terminal, phpmyadmin

I have a text file with 400k of data named data.txt example

```
row1,row2,row3
1111,2222,33333
4444,5555,6666
777,8888,9999
1010101010,111111111,12121212
13313131313,14141414141414,151515151515
```

but when i try to import it directly it gives error

I want to import it to a database named 'dataflow.sql'

and let it create 3 rows with the names from the example and fetch the data based on the comas

any help is appreciated

Comment: *when i try to import it directly* Where is destination table structure and importing query? *it gives error* Where is complete error message? *I want to import it to a database named `'dataflow.sql'`* This looks like not database but dump file name.

Comment: i was trying to import from the web gui of phpmy admin and it was saying file to big NGINX as the file is 18 MB @Akina

Comment: Try to increase `max_allowed_packet` setting (edit connection settings).

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to craft a SQL request using LOAD DATA:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/data.txt' 
INTO TABLE my_table 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: it says ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement